# Customize Drupal URL by content type

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-7

I have set up a content type - cars. Is there a way to automatically add the prefix /cars/ before the id? So for example domain.com/cars/2. I may also have more content types which I need to do this for. Standard pages however need no prefix.

How can I change the URL format based on the content type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module was built for exactly that:

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pathauto module with token [content-type]/[node]